# php iis 7.5 500 error

Tags: php, iis-7

i manually installed PHP, following a guide http://www.peterguy.com/php/install_IIS6.html#phpConfigure.  i am trying to run in on IIS 7.5

i am receiving this error:

```
Module: IsapiModule

Notification:   ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler:    PHP

Error Code: 0x8007007f
```

and i cant make heads or tails of it.  i made a blank file called test.php that gives the error, a similar file called test.html, also blank, does not give an error.

i made an application pool, allowed the php5isapi.dll, etc.

NOTE: no error logs are created, although i configured php.ini to create logs in a specific folder.

Comment: Why do you use a installation instruction for IIS6? Use the [Web Plattform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53) from Microsoft and your PHP setup will run in 5 minutes without any configuration ...

Comment: well that was easy.  thank you!

Comment: Anecdote: as a very high-and-mighty sysadmin I avoided using the Web Platform Installer for months. PHP *worked*, but it was a pain in the butt and often had problems. One day I broke down and used WPI and it's dead-simple and most everything works right away.

Comment: @Olaf Broggson: No problem :-)